# How to calculate the euclidian distance between a specified coordinate and 2-d xarray data at once

Tags: python, python-xarray

How to calculate the euclidian distance between a specified coordinate and 2-d xarray data at once (without for loop)?

I wrote the following code. But if the data-size become larger, this script appears to be slow. How can I do the same thing without for loop ?

```py
import math
import xarray as xr 
import numpy as np

#set the specified lat, lon
specific_lat = 15
specific_lon = 65

#create sample xarry data
lat = [0, 10, 20]
lon = [50, 60, 70, 80]

#sample data
test_data = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])

#to xarray
data_xarray = xr.DataArray(test_data, dims=("lat","lon"), coords={"lat":lat, "lon":lon})

#calculate distance
xarray_distance = data_xarray #copy
xarray_distance.data[:,:] = 0.0 #zero-reset

for lat in data_xarray.lat.data:
    for lon in data_xarray.lon.data:
        xarray_distance.loc[{"lat":lat,"lon":lon}] = math.sqrt((lat- spec_lat)**2 + (lon - spec_lon)**2)

print(xarray_distance)

#<xarray.DataArray (lat: 3, lon: 4)>
#array([[21, 15, 15, 21],
#       [15,  7,  7, 15],
#       [15,  7,  7, 15]])
#Coordinates:
#  * lat      (lat) int64 0 10 20
#  * lon      (lon) int64 50 60 70 80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, `xarray_distance = data_xarray` does not copy the object. Both names will see the same object and any changes that occur to it equally. For a copy, you want to do `data_xarray.copy()`.

Now, instead of using loops, you want to take advantage of numpy's vectorisation and broadcasting to create the 2D array in one go and set that to your xarray's object data.

```
lat = np.array(lat)
lon = np.array(lon)
xarray_distance.data = np.sqrt((lat - spec_lat)[:,None]**2 + ((lon - spec_lon)**2))
```

Result

```
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 3, lon: 4)>
array([[21.21320344, 15.8113883 , 15.8113883 , 21.21320344],
       [15.8113883 ,  7.07106781,  7.07106781, 15.8113883 ],
       [15.8113883 ,  7.07106781,  7.07106781, 15.8113883 ]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) int32 0 10 20
  * lon      (lon) int32 50 60 70 80
```

You'll notice the data are floats, as they should probably be, considering what they represent. If you want them in the original type of the data, substitute

```
xarray_distance.data = np.sqrt(...)
```

with

```
xarray_distance.data = np.sqrt(...).astype(xarray_distance.data.dtype)
```

Comment: Thank you for ryour replying. I could done that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate Cosine weighting by: `(lon - spec_lon)**2` and that is equal to `(cos(lat)*(lon - spec_lon))`